# How compatible is OpenJRE/JDK 1.8.x vs OracleJRE/JDK 1.8.x?

Tags: java, oraclejdk

Looks like all Linux distros only have available OpenJDK.

How do them compare today? Can I just go with OpenJDK for server related things (Jenkins, Java web frameworks like Play, Vertx, etc)?

Or should I still go with Oracle JDK/JRE to be safe?

Comment: Actually not a really dup here. This is specific to JDK 8. And the other thread addresses only JDK 7 (as the question is from 2013). The question should be if differences between OpenJDK and OracleJDK still exist in Java 8.

Comment: Exactly. That was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like all Linux distros only have available OpenJDK.

You can of course install any version you wish.  You don't have to use the built in one.

> How do them compare today?

The updates are not exactly in sync and there is some proprietary additions in the Oracle JVM but they have the same code base.

> Or should I still go with Oracle JDK/JRE to be safe?

It's up to you. It's unlikely to made a difference for you.